# Bone has a weird offset even though all its transform values are zeroes

Tags: animation, armature, bones, transforms

[image]

I am trying to parent a weapon bone (Weapon.R) to my hand bone (CC_Base_Hand.R), but I keep getting this weird offset between the 2 (highlighted with an arrow) and I don't know how to clear it. This offset also varies between files, so I can't move animations from one file to another, because same values mean different things because of this offset. It's like there are some hidden values at play, or something.

Anyone has any idea what this is and how to get rid of it? This is driving me crazy!

Comment: hello, maybe share your armature? https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... Also maybe you should do the opposite, i.e. parent the hand to the weapon, but it's another question...

Comment: Did you use IK? It looks like problems with bone's rotation and you should have this option. Like a checkbox or whatever it is now.